# Deterministic radius of convergence of power series

Tags: probability, probability-theory, power-series

Let $X_i$'s be i.i.d. random variables. Consider the random power series

\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty = X_n z^n
\end{equation*}

Is there any deterministic (almost surely) radius of convergence of the above series in the following two cases 
(a): $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = -1)$ = 1/2
(b): $X_i$ follows N(0; 1). 
If so, find the radius.

Comment: Hint: (a) is extremely obvious, using e.g. Root Test or Ratio Test.  (b) only slightly less obvious using Root Test.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Your question will attract more potential answerers if you give some extra context, such as what you’ve tried, or your motivation. You can add such extra info in an edit.

Comment: This is the subject of Chapter IV (Random Taylor Series) of Jean-Pierre Kahane's _Some random series of functions_ ; the results are too complex to summarize here.  The radius of convergence is tail-measurable, and hence a.s. constant.  I think the answer for (a) is $r=1$.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick reply. @kimchilover Can you explain why you found 1 for a) ?

Comment: Root test, as Robert said.

Comment: @kimchilover Any chance you show me the beginning to do it with probability and not a function? In fact i feel more confident doing the b)

Comment: I have tried to answer your comment in an "answer".  If it is misdirected, let me know and I will edit it, or remove it, or ask Robert to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

For each $\omega\in\Omega$ we have $R(\omega)=1/\limsup_{n\to\infty}|X_n(\omega)|^{1/n}= 1$, in case (a) (obviously) and also (only slightly less obviously, according to Robert) in case (b), with probability 1.